# xStream deserialisation of HashMap<String, List<String>> XML File

Tags: java, xml, file, deserialization, xstream

serialisation works fine, but desirialisation wount work.
I will post my Code and the errors copies from Eclipse.

```
    <dependency>      <!-- for XML -->
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4c</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code:

```
    public static void serialize(File file, Graph g) {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> imageTMP = g.getImageURLmap();
    HashMap<Coordinate, String> coordTMP = g.getCoordMap();
    // ... and serialize it via XMLEncoder to file
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStream buff = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(buff, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        xStream.toXML(imageTMP, writer);
        xStream.toXML(coordTMP, outputStream);
        writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void deserializeImage(File file, Graph g) {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> imageTMP;
    HashMap<Coordinate, String> coordTMP;
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream buff = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(buff, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        ObjectInputStream in = xStream.createObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        imageTMP = (HashMap<String, List<String>>) in.readObject();
        coordTMP = (HashMap<Coordinate, String>) in.readObject();
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        imageTMP = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        coordTMP = new HashMap<Coordinate, String>();
    }
    g.setImageURLmap(imageTMP);
    g.setCoordMap(coordTMP);
}
```

The XML:

```
    <map>
      <entry>
        <string>Netto</string>
        <list/>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <string>Sparkasse</string>
        <list>
          <string>http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Salem_Rechnung.jpg</string>
          <string>http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/8/83/Sparkasse.svg</string>
          <string>http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/3/38/ErsteBank_Sparkasse_Logo.svg</string>
          <string>http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Caixa_Manlleu_branch.JPG</string>
        </list>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <string>Bohlmann und Meyer</string>
        <list/>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <string>Langwedel</string>
        <list/>
      </entry>
    </map><map>
      <entry>
        <com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate>
          <x>9.18013565</x>
          <y>52.983609799999996</y>
          <z>NaN</z>
        </com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate>
        <string> </string>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate>
          <x>9.1815044</x>
          <y>52.9855979</y>
          <z>NaN</z>
        </com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate>
        <string> </string>
      </entry>
    </map>
```

With new XStream(); I get:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot construct java.util.Map$Entry : java.util.Map$Entry : Cannot construct java.util.Map$Entry : java.util.Map$Entry
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot construct java.util.Map$Entry : java.util.Map$Entry
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException
cause-message       : Cannot construct java.util.Map$Entry : java.util.Map$Entry
class               : java.util.Map$Entry
required-type       : java.util.Map$Entry
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /entry
line number         : 1
version             : 1.4.7
-------------------------------
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1185)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1157)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$4.readFromStream(XStream.java:1851)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.CustomObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(CustomObjectInputStream.java:120)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
       at org.opentripplanner.util.SeMo_Wiki.deserializeImage(SeMo_Wiki.java:255)
       at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.GraphBuilderTask.run(GraphBuilderTask.java:153)
       at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.main(OTPMain.java:61)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException: Cannot construct java.util.Map$Entry : java.util.Map$Entry
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SunLimitedUnsafeReflectionProvider.newInstance(SunLimitedUnsafeReflectionProvider.java:80)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.instantiateNewInstance(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:553)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:256)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
       ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.Map$Entry
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance(Native Method)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SunLimitedUnsafeReflectionProvider.newInstance(SunLimitedUnsafeReflectionProvider.java:76)
       ... 16 more
```

And with new XStream(new DomDriver());

```
[Fatal Error] :127:8: Markup im Dokument nach dem Root-Element muss ordnungsgemäß formatiert sein.
com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : Markup im Dokument nach dem Root-Element muss ordnungsgemäß formatiert sein.
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver.createReader(DomDriver.java:105)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver.createReader(DomDriver.java:77)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.createObjectInputStream(XStream.java:1812)
       at org.opentripplanner.util.SeMo_Wiki.deserializeImage(SeMo_Wiki.java:253)
       at org.opentripplanner.graph_builder.GraphBuilderTask.run(GraphBuilderTask.java:153)
       at org.opentripplanner.standalone.OTPMain.main(OTPMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 127; columnNumber: 8; Markup im Dokument nach dem Root-Element muss ordnungsgemäß formatiert sein.
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
       at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver.createReader(DomDriver.java:98)
       ... 5 more
```

Did anyone has an advice for me? I totaly tried out everything I can mention?
Even ONLY the simplier `HashMap<Coordinate, String>` alone does not work (`HashMap<String, List<String>>` so not seems to be the problem with generics or so on...)

Greatings D.

Comment: Use Converter to serialize and deserialize your objects:http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/collections/MapConverter.html

Comment: Maps should be done per default xStream implementation. So that would be reinventing the wheel. Or can you give me an Converter example and explain why this is necessary?

Comment: I think it is not possible to read two successive objects from a stream without a XML root element. Your XML has this structure: `<map>...</map><map>...</map>`. Please try out to compose your two maps into a root class, e.g. *Supermarkets*, and serialize the root object.